# How to add in the parameter for MotionEvent

Tags: android

I have written some codes to get the location from ImageView. Below is my code:

```
private void touchLocation(MotionEvent e){
float x = e.getX();
float y = e.getY();

String message = "Location is x = " + x + ", y = " + y ".";

Context context = getApplicationContext();
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG:

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
toast.show();
```

}

In the onCreate() method, how shall I call this function? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. How shall I instantiate an object with the class MotionEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

     float x = e.getX();
     float y = e.getY();

     String message = "Location is x = " + x + ", y = " + y ".";

     // more code

     return true;
     }
 });
```

Comment: I get the error "The method setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnTouchListener(){})". Why? And how to solve it?

Comment: Make sure that you imported the listener correctly, you need `import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;` at the top of your file with the other imports.